Minimum supported Gradle version is 8.7. Current version is 8.2. Android
I want to run the command gradle detekt on Android Studio's terminal but I always get the error:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 8.7. Current version is 8.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\...\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-8.7-all.zip

But my gradle-wrapper.properties is the following:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

It is already set on gradle-8.7-all.zip I also have invalidated cache and restarted.
On project structure I have this

Why AS is still saying that my version is 8.2 when I run the command?
I have the "Wrapper" distribution on Gradle settings

Thanks

Make sure that in the Gradle settings it is configured to use the Gradle distribution from "Wrapper", not "Local Installation". Let me know if that was your problem, then I make it an answer that you can up-vote and accept.

Yeah I have "wrapper" already in the distribution.
When I set to "Local instalation" AS shows the gradle folder and that one says 8.2
Can I download a newwer one??

Oh, sorry, totally misread that you are not running Gradle from AS integration but from terminal embedded in AS. Then Simon's answer is already correct. Never use gradle to run a Gradle build, but always the Gradle wrapper which defines and manages the Gradle version to use. Any setting in AS is pointless when you run Gradle from a terminal.

When you run gradle you are running the Gradle version installed globally on your system.
To use the locally installed wrapper, you need to run the file gradlew instead (or gradlew.bat on Windows), located in your project root directory1.

1 Documentation

gradlew is just for Mac, I'm on windows

gradlew.bat then

gradlew is not just for Mac, it is for all *nix systems, so also Linux and so on. Besides that, calling gradlew in Windows still works, as it automatically starts the gradlew.bat. ;-)

I just had this problem and invalidating cache fixed the issue.
File > Invalidate Caches...

